# iPhone - inserting space between custom table cells in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with custom cells in it. I'd like to add a little red bar between the cells to have the cells be more distinct.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `separatorStyle` and `separatorColor` properties of the `UITableView`.  For example:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
  self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor redColor];
  self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
}
```

That style is the default, there are some others, but depending on what OS you are targeting (the etched style is only available as of 3.2, for example).

[Apple's docs on the UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle)

Comment: I saw this - is there any way to make the line thicker?

Comment: Great question.  I'd like to know the answer to that myself.  I reckon there is, probably the best way to do this is to add a few pixel high view to the bottom of each cell, but not on the last cell in a section.

Also, in the future - please add things you've already tried to your question, it'll help everyone give you more the answers you're looking for :)

Answer (score -1):

1- Override

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

If indexPath.row % 2 == 1 (odd indexpath row), remove the text on your cell, set red as background color and return that cell. If you are populating your table using an array, you have to take that extra red cells into account and populate accordingly.

2 - Write a custom UITableView cell with some extra red space on the bottom, and return that cel on cellForRowAtIndexPath. Remove the red space on the bottom cell if necessary.

Comment: Don't know, kind of feels like abusing the UITableView.

Comment: I don't think so. Now that I am reviewing the question, I would say simply setting the backgroundColor of the table as [UIColor redColor] and overriding heightForRowAtIndexPath to return cell height + red space should do the trick instead of my first solution, which sort of complicate things. And I have used my second solution to insert a subview into the cell with an animation, that did not seem wrong for me, but I am open for suggestions.